# Como ocultar parte del codigo html con php

Tags: php, html

tengo un inconveniente, quiero ocultar una parte del código html con php, para ello realizo algunas validaciones en php y si estas no se cumplen ocupo la función **die();** logrando ocultar el contenido html, pero resulta ser que se oculta todo el contenido y solo quiero ocultar una parte de el. Estoy realizando esto a modo de prueba para ya pasarlo al script definitivo.

Adjunto el código y de antemano muchas gracias.

```
<?php
$error = '';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['clave'])){
        echo 'ingrese un usuario y contraseña';     
    }else{
        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
        $clave = $_POST['clave'];
        if($usuario == 'jonhy' && $clave == '12345'){
            echo 'Usuario correcto';
        }else{
            die('error');
        }
    }   
}
?>

<!--Este parte igual debe seguir mostrandose-->
<div>
    <p>Codigo html a mostrar</p>
</div>
<!--Si falla la validacion, solo se debe ocultar el formulario-->
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="usuario">
    <input type="text" name="clave">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="enviar">
    
</form>
<!--De aqui hacia abajo debe seguir mostrandose-->
<div>
    <p>Resto del contenido html que quiero que se muestre </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes declarar una variable de estilo al comienzo de tu código para después poder agregarla al formulario que quieres ocultar de ser erróneo el logueo del usuario.

Sería algo así:

```
    <?php
$error = '';
$formulario = "
    <form action='' method='post'>
        <input type='text' name='usuario'>
        <input type='text' name='clave'>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='enviar'>    
    </form>";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['clave'])){
        echo 'ingrese un usuario y contraseña';     
    }else{
        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
        $clave = $_POST['clave'];
        if($usuario == 'jonhy' && $clave == '12345'){
            echo 'Usuario correcto';
        }else{
            $formulario = '';
        }
    }   
}
?>

<!--Este parte igual debe seguir mostrandose-->
<div>
    <p>Codigo html a mostrar</p>
</div>
<!--Si falla la validacion, solo se debe ocultar el formulario-->
<?php echo $formulario;?>
<!--De aqui hacia abajo debe seguir mostrandose-->
<div>
    <p>Resto del contenido html que quiero que se muestre </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Pero con lo que me mencionas tu, solo bastaría con que alguien entre al editor de código del navegador y ponga la opción en display:block y aparece nuevamente

Comment: Ok, entonces sería como la nueva corrección, en la cuál se agrega el formulario dentro de una variable inicializada en tu php para posteriormente solo imprimir su contenido y evitar su acceso a través de la consola del navegador.

Answer (score 0):

Asigna a una variable, en este caso `$error` el estado de la operación. Dicho en otras palabras, que sea una bandera que indique si hubo o no error en la autenticación.

```
<?php
$error = 0;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['clave'])){
        echo 'ingrese un usuario y contraseña';     
    }else{
        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
        $clave = $_POST['clave'];
        if($usuario == 'jonhy' && $clave == '12345'){
            echo 'Usuario correcto';
        }else{
            $error = 1;
        }
    }   
}
?>
```

En la parte del formulario compruebas el estado de esa bandera, en este caso, si se mantiene en 0 es indicador de que no hubo error

```
<?php if($error == 0) { ?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="usuario">
    <input type="text" name="clave">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Aunque esto funciona no es recomendable trabajar de esta manera, ya que conforme pasa el tiempo el código se vuelve difícil de leer y mantener. Te sugiero utilices javascript, hagas peticiones ajax a un archivo php aparte y retornes la respuesta y ocultas o no los elementos que desees.

Comment: Entonces tengo mi pagina de login supongamos en index.php donde esta todo el formulario y el action del form apunta a login.php , me dices tu que el formulario lo ponga en otro archivo aparte y lo muestre via ajax , para luego al enviar el formulario según la respuesta obtenida ocultar o no el formulario, o te refieres a poner el formulario en una variable dentro del login.php y retornarla por ajax según las validaciones

Comment: Lo que quiero decir es que separes el código HTML del PHP, hay diversas formas de trabajar un login. La respuesta que te di asume que están en un mismo archivo. Si ya están separados es correcto, el archivo JS donde estará el ajax se encargará de "conectarlos", esto permitirá que no se recargue toda tu pagina, también podrás trabajar de mejor manera en la presentación de los errores y así mismo mostrar u ocultar elementos del DOM